# categorical logic and computation

Tags: category-theory, computational-complexity, computability, categorical-logic

After encountering the field of Categorical Logic recently, and more specifically the nLab page on Computational Trilogy as well as [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5762.pdf) paper, I'm under the impression that we have a pretty complete categorical formalization of at least one of the several equivalent fundamental notions of computation. Given this, I have two probably extremely naive questions:

(i) Have we tried to categorify computational *complexity* theory?

(ii) If (i) is somehow possible, could we hope that maybe "functorial invariants'' have something to say about identification problems? Like $P = NP$?

I am curious whether the above even make sense and whether any work has been done which could be said to pursue them.

Comment: You might want to see "monoidal computers" I and III. (I have not read the whole thing but in III the authors say something like II was not so successful.)